# VSCode: Add snippets to semantic completions?

Tags: javascript, visual-studio-code, autocomplete, intellisense, code-snippets

In VSCode, is it possible to tap into semantic suggestions and modify what's inserted when that suggestion is accepted?

In other words, in a JavaScript file, typing in `myArr.r` will show the `reduce` method. But accepting it just gives you `myArr.reduce`. I'd like to have it insert a snippet instead (with tabstops and placeholders), that looks something like this: `myArr.reduce((accumulator, currentValue) => {});`.

Of course, we have the ability to create our own snippets. But they aren't semantic (`reduce` will show up as a suggestion at all times), causing the quick suggestion list to become bloated.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does not appear to be possible at the moment, but I have submitted a [feature request](https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/issues/80890) to VSCode's GitHub repo.